# Selecting one per group

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

- TenantServer
- Result

The [TenantServer] has a 1-to-Many relationship with the [Result] table. As a TenantServer can have multiple Results. An example below shows the TenantServer (DBName) column with multiple Results (Type and Date).

[image]

What I'm trying to do is get the 1 latest row foreach DBName and Type, for example:

WintrixVictorMillwell, Log, (date here)

WintrixRAC, Log, (date here)

WintrixComfort, Log, (date here)

Each DBName can have 2 different types also, these are "Log" and "Full"

I'm not sure how I would acheive this, so far I've been able to get the latest rows since the last 24 hours but i cant seem to figure out how to get 1 latest row for each of them.

Comment: `Max(DATE)` and remove Date from the `Group By` and `Order By`

Comment: @WEI_DBA Can you post an answer please, because I'm not sure what you mean>

Comment: `Select DBName, [Type], MAX([Date]) ... ` and remove `[Date]` From the `Group By` clause and `Order By` clause. Also, look at the link it's been answered many times over.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column